# Cassandra: Undefined column name permissions

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra throws an exception:

`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Undefined column name permissions at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy (InvalidQueryException.java:50) at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause (DriverThrowables.java:37) at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare (AbstractSession.java:100) at org.accells.connection.CassandraSession.prepare(CassandraSession.java:120)`

Unfortunately I can't find any info about this in the net. Please, advice.
The line that throwing this exception is cassandra code :

```
/**
 * Prepares the provided query string.
 *
 * @param query the CQL query string to prepare
 * @return the prepared statement corresponding to {@code query}.
 * @throws NoHostAvailableException if no host in the cluster can be
 *                                  contacted successfully to prepare this query.
 */
PreparedStatement prepare(String query);
```

The query provided is SQL valid query.

Comment: can you add the actual query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is telling you that the column `permissions` does not exist on the table you are trying to query it from.

It comes from here:

```
ColumnDefinition def = cfm.getColumnDefinition(id);
if (def == null)
    throw new InvalidRequestException(String.format("Undefined column name %s", toString()));
return def;
```

in `ColumnDefinition.java` (I haven't linked to the code because I don't know what version you are running.

Comment: OMG, you are right. So stupid mistake. Thanks a lot. I was thinking for a day what kind of permissions do I need.